# Converting multiple strings into one

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert multiple strings into one simple dialogue from a NPC. Basically what I'm trying to do is make a list of all the skills a player has 200M experience in and output it into a NPC dialogue.

OLD

```
        if (componentId == OPTION_4) {
            sendNPCDialogue(npcId, 9827, "You can prestige: "+maxedSkills()+"");
        }

private String maxedSkills() {
    return ""+attackMax()+""+strengthMax()+""+defenceMax()+"";
}

public String attackMax() {
    if (player.getSkills().getXp(Skills.ATTACK) == 200000000)
    return "Attack, ";
    else
    return "";
}

public String strengthMax() {
    if (player.getSkills().getXp(Skills.STRENGTH) == 200000000)
    return "Strength, ";
    else
    return "";
}

public String defenceMax() {
    if (player.getSkills().getXp(Skills.DEFENCE) == 200000000)
    return "Defence, ";
    else
    return "";
}
```

With that code I have it working, but that is a lot of code to add due to there being 25 different skills. How would I create a way to make all of the skills be referenced into one? Here are all of the skill names:

```
public static final String[] SKILL_NAME = { "Attack", "Defence", "Strength", "Constitution", "Ranged", "Prayer",
        "Magic", "Cooking", "Woodcutting", "Fletching", "Fishing", "Firemaking", "Crafting", "Smithing", "Mining",
        "Herblore", "Agility", "Thieving", "Slayer", "Farming", "Runecrafting", "Hunter", "Construction",
        "Summoning", "Dungeoneering" };
```

New and working (for attack/strength/defence):

```
public static final int[] SKILL_TYPE = {Skills.ATTACK, Skills.STRENGTH, Skills.DEFENCE};

public String maxedSkills() { 
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i = 0; i < SKILL_TYPE.length; i++) { 
        if (player.getSkills().getXp(i) == 200000000) {
        if(sb.length()>0) sb.append(", ");
        sb.append(Skills.SKILL_NAME[i]);
        }
      }
    if(sb.length()>0) sb.append(".");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: What is "NPC" and "NPC dialog"?

Comment: That's the Non-Player Character and their dialogue to the user

Comment: One of the most pleasant, under advertised, highly welcomed additions to the API in recent years [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) - so awesome, I "borrowed" it and put into our library base when we weren't allowed to use Java 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a StringBuffer (thread safe) or a StringBuilder and do something like this.

```
....
public static final Skills[] SKILL_TYPE = {Skills.Attack, Skills.Defence, ...};

public String getBigString() { 
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int nSkills = 0, lSkill = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < SKILL_TYPE.length; i++ )
      { 
      if( player.getSkills().getXp(SKILL_TYPE[i]) == K_SOMELEVEL ) {
        if(nSkills > 0) sb.append(", ");
        lSkill = sb.length(); // track position of last skill in string
        nSkills += 1;
        sb.append(SKILL_NAME[i]);
        }
      }
    if( nSkills > 0 ) 
      { 
      if( nSkills > 1 ) sb.insert( lSkill, "and ");
      sb.append(".");
      }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: This worked except for the exception that it shows the SkillID numbers instead of the Skill names.. For example it would show I can have 0, 2 instead of Attack Strength

Comment: Check you are using skill name and not type.  If it is a string, it should append that string.

Comment: Ah, I did append it to the int and not the Skils.SKILL_NAME[I] like I should've. This fixed it right up and now it works perfectly. Thank you for helping me shorten and fix the code Micromuncher!

Comment: Just one more question, and idk if this is possible but it would be nice to have. Is there a way to add a "and" string infront of the last skill if there are 2+ skills listed? Here is the picture of what I'm talking about. http://prntscr.com/kkpnpb

Comment: Absolutely,  You saw the logic for comma and period.  Do something similar for 2 or more skills.  So, I'll modify the answer to show ut,

Comment: I tried editing it to make it detect if there are two SKILL_NAME to only do the "and " instead of the , and (For example: "Attack, and Strength". Is there a way to add that into it without causing too much trouble?

Comment: You're now asking me to do it for you. If you only have 2 skills, remove the last character (,)...

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be to have a parameteried method that takes the `Skill` type as input. Here is how it would look like:

```
public String skillMax(Skills skill) {
    if (player.getSkills().getXp(skill) == 200000000)
    return skill.getName() + ", ";
    else
    return "";
}
```

The next thing to do is to provide a `name` to the skill in `Skills` enum. Something like this should work:

```
public enum Skills {
    DEFENSE("Defense"), ...;
    private String name;
    Skills(String name) { this.name = name; }
    String getName() { return this.name; }
}
```

Comment: I converted it into my code to make it sort of work, except now I'm getting an error on the return ""+skillName.getName()+""; part because it wants to make it static.. But you can't make the String getName() static and still return the name...http://prntscr.com/kkm9hh

Comment: Thank you for your help. but Micromuncher's code seemed to work pretty well with what I was going for. I could definitely use your example in a few other codes in the future and it taught me a bit about enums and the way to cast it. Very helpful.